# On Scroll up SwipetoRefresh enables in android?

Tags: android

I have a SwipeToRefresh when I scroll down listview and when scroll up Swipe to refresh gets enable without going on top of listview and also want to clear all data from listview and add new data it works fine but when I scroll down and send request it only show progress at bottom not adding data .How can I avoid this problem.pls let me know .

code:-

```
private void getDetails() {// get details of user from shared preference...
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());// crating object of Login Session
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();// get String from Login Session
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...
    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...
    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();// making object of Arraylist

}

private void init() {// initialize controls


    m_ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);// finding Id of progressview
    m_ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);// make profressView Invisible first time
    m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);// findind Id of Listview
    m_ListView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    /*Swipe to refresh code*/
    mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);


    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        postDealListingDatatoServer();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh_progress_1);

    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            /*Here check net connection avialable or not */
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {

                s_oDataset.clear();
                m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                m_ListView.invalidate();
                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                swipeData();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {

                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable = false;
            if (m_ListView != null && m_ListView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                // check if the first item of the list is visible
                boolean firstItemVisible = m_ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                // check if the top of the first item is visible
                boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = m_ListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                // enabling or disabling the refresh layout
                enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
            }
            mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    });
    m_n_FormImage = new int[]{// defining Images in Integer array
            R.drawable.amazon,
            R.drawable.whatsapp,
            R.drawable.zorpia,
            R.drawable.path,
            R.drawable.app_me,
            R.drawable.evernote,
            R.drawable.app_me};


}

    /*This is new changes in code ....using Volley instead of AsynkTask*/

/*This method send request to server for deallisting*/
// this method send request to server for deal list....
public void postDealListingDatatoServer() {
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Request:-" + json);
        m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Please wait while loading deals...");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                        item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                        s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                    }
                    mFooter = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.footer, null);


                    if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                        // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                        m_ListView.addFooterView(mFooter);// add footer in listview
                        m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                        m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                    } else {
                        mFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                    }
                    m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                            if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
                                if (!isLoading) {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                                        m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                                        m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above
                                        String itemscount = String.valueOf(m_ListView.getAdapter().getCount());
                                        System.out.println("Toatal item:-" + itemscount);

                                        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                                        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                                        loadmoreData();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                isLoading = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                        mFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Errror:-" + error);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/*This method send request to server for more deals*/
//this method post request to server to fetch more deal
public void loadmoreData() {

    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Server Request:-" + json);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                        if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                            s_oDataset.add(item);
                            isLoading = false;
                            m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                        mFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*This method invoke on swipe to refresh*/
// this method invoke when swipe to refresh enable ....
public void swipeData() {
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Server Request:-" + json);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                        item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                        s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                    }
                    mFooter = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.footer, null);


                    if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                        // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                        m_ListView.addFooterView(mFooter);// add footer in listview
                        m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                        m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                    } else {
                        mFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                    }
                    m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                            if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
                                if (!isLoading) {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                                        m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                                        m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above
                                        String itemscount = String.valueOf(m_ListView.getAdapter().getCount());
                                        System.out.println("Toatal item:-" + itemscount);

                                        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                                        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                                        loadmoreData();// this method load more deals from server ....
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

XML which contain swipe to refresh :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/deal_list_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

code for :- @layout/deal_list_content

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!---->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dealList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    </ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the XML file that contains the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/deal_list_content"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

Comment: what does `deal_list_content.xml` contain ? post that as well please

Answer (score 0):

SwipeRefreshView can only support one direct child. If I'm not wrong, it should only encapsulate @id/dealList.

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` can have just one direct child. Change your layout to something along the lines of -

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <SwipeRefreshLayout ...>

        <ListView ...../>

    </SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```